# Can't get why javascript skips the number of iterator in loop

Tags: javascript

Here is a task
Given a 2D binary matrix filled with 0's and 1's, find the largest square containing only 1's and return its area.

Example:

Input:

1 0 1 0 0

1 0 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 1 0

Output: 4

Below is my answer what I wrote, it passes 25 test cases and then gets stuck on this one below. It gives answer 25, except accepted 4. So it means for me that it thinks that the whole matrix contains ones. Okay Then a problem is in if statement `if(matrix[j][i] === "0")` in function `find_max`. Then I consoled logged `j` and indeed I don't know why but when it iterates through it skips number 2.. I have no clue why. It goes 0, 1, 3. Give it a quick look if you can find any mistake, if no don't worry I'll try to rewrite it.

```
  let maximalSquare = mx([
["1","1","1","1","1"],
["1","1","1","1","1"],
["0","0","0","0","0"],
["1","1","1","1","1"],
["1","1","1","1","1"]

]);
console.log(maximalSquare);

function mx(matrix) {
    let max_length = 0;
    let cur_length = 0;
    if(matrix.length === 0)
        return 0;
    if(matrix.length === 1){
            let arr = new Set(matrix[0]);
    
            arr.has("1") ? max_length = 1 : max_length = 0
            return max_length;
        }
    
        for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for (let j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] === "1"){
                    cur_length = find_max(matrix, 2, j, i);
                    max_length = Math.max(cur_length, max_length);
                }
            }
        }
        return max_length * max_length;
    };
    
    function find_max(matrix, newSquerSize, x, y){
        let i = x;
        let j = y;
    
        if(x + newSquerSize > matrix.length || y + newSquerSize > matrix.length){
            return newSquerSize - 1;
        }
        while(j < y + newSquerSize && j < matrix.length){
            while(i < x + newSquerSize && i < matrix.length){
                console.log(j, matrix[j][i])
                if(matrix[j][i] === "0") //here where it doesnt iterate through j = 2
                    return newSquerSize - 1;
                ++i;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        return find_max(matrix, ++newSquerSize, x, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first guess on the reason why the 2 is skipped would be that j incremented twice. In this case it means on the next iteration of j, the while loop of i didn't was immediately skipped
(i.e `i >= x + newSquerSize || i >= matrix.length`)

Since you're looping through lines/columns for the square, shouldn't you reset the i index to the starting value ?

I did try adding a `i = x;` before that loop and the result was indeed 4 as stated.

```
while (j < y + newSquerSize && j < matrix.length) 
{
  i = x;  // Add this line 
  while (i < x + newSquerSize && i < matrix.length) {
    console.log(j, i, matrix[j][i]);
    if (matrix[j][i] === "0")
      return newSquerSize - 1;
    ++i;
  }
  ++j;
}
```

Comment: you are smart. YESS!! How could I forget reset it......

Comment: thouthands thanks again, you dont know what I have been throught. 5 hours I was solving it and another 2 hours was looking for mistake